# Does personification of animals in fictional media like Peppa Pig and Donald Duck promote cultural reconsideration of those animals as delicacies?

Tags: outreach, scientific-studies, history, culture

I [wondered](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/112576/why-is-peppa-a-pig) whether Peppa was a pig to promote the idea of pigs as lovable pets rather than delicacies. It [turns out](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/112577/78993) that it wasn't the case.

However, that led me wondering if there is any evidence that such personification of animals in fictional media leads to a change in the outlook of individuals and/or societies towards those animals?

I would be grateful if the experts here could please enlighten.

Comment: this is not really a veganism question ... it is more of a question about peoples reactions ... the question is probably a better fit at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola I understand. Please allow me to explain myself. As a lifelong vegetarian, I don't have many questions about vegetarianism. However, I want to support the community and found that the number of questions was low. So, I asked this question here.

Comment: I don't really have an answer. However, the number of barbecue restaurants around me that both (1) have anthropomorphized animal mascots (cow, pig, and/or chicken), and (2) are popular with meat eaters, suggest that representation of people-like animals isn't enough on its own to encourage people towards being more respectful.

Comment: @Erica Could you please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was watching Schindlers' List a few days back. Looking back at what people are capable of doing to their fellow humans if society allows it. I don't have much hope about anthropomorphized cartoons preventing people from doing what they want to do. Here we are talking about suppressing one of the strongest things that drive a human, eating. Plus, the fulfilment of this biological urge has zero social consequences. I vote, cartoons are not going to do anything.

What will however prevent people from eating an animal is if they identify it as a unique living creature that has a personality and form an emotional bond with it. Then they will be willing to kill and die before they eat that thing.

So I guess, if the animal is in the in-group of the person then its sort of naturally blasphemous to eat the animal but otherwise its fair game.